# Showing $f(0) = 0$ and $|f'(x)| \leq M$ implies $|f(x)| \leq M |x|$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(0)=0$ and $|f'(x)|\leq M$. Prove that $|f(x)|\leq M|x|$. Apply this to the function $f(x)=\sin x$.

I'm unsure of how to prove this problem. This problem is from the Mean Value Theorem section chapter. I will ask question if in doubt of the proof provided.

Comment: Of course, you're assuming $\,f\,$ is differentiable, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322890/uniform-continuity-of-fx-x3).

**Mean Value Theorem:** If a function $f$ is continuous on the closed interval [a, b], where a < b, and differentiable on the open interval (a, b), then there exists a point c in (a, b) such that
$$ f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}. $$

Apply this to your problem gives

$$ f'(c) = \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0},\quad c\in(0,x) $$

$$ \implies \left| \frac{f(x)}{x}\right|=|f'(c)| \leq M \implies |f(x)|\leq M |x|.$$

Now, apply this to $\sin(x)$ and figure out what $M$.

Comment: would we still use (0,x)?

Comment: is it  |sin x| <= M |x|?

Comment: @Maximiliano: When $f(x)=\sin(x)$, we have $f'(c)=\cos(c)$ which implies $ |f'(c)|=|\cos(c)|\leq 1 = M. $

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = \int_0^x f'(t) dt$
so $|f(x)| = |\int_0^x f'(t) dt|
\le \int_0^x |f'(t)| dt
\le \int_0^x M dt
= M x
$.

Note: this seems too easy, so I might be misapplying something
or assuming something that is not necessarily true. 
Or I might actually be right - that sometimes happens.

Comment: Unfortunately, not this time :(. You assumed the derivative is integrable. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra's_function).

Comment: Oh well, that's the way the cookie bounces.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you had an $x$ such that $|f(x)| > M|x|.$ See what the mean value theorem gives you applied to the interval $(0,x).$

Comment: Im unsure how to do it

Comment: @Maximiliano Do you know the full statement of the mean value theorem?

Comment: Yes its the what mhenni wrote up above and it what I have in my textbook. But its that last part which Im stuck how to apply it to the problem f(x)=sin x