# Uniform Continuity of $f(x)=x^3$

Tags: analysis, continuity

1.)Determine whether $f(x)=x^3$ is uniformly continuous on [0,2)

So far, I have $\delta$ = 2 and $\epsilon$ = 8, and plan on using the sandwich theorem with $x^2$ and eventually equating $\delta = \epsilon$.

Comment: Certainly, when $\epsilon=8$ you can do it, but you need to find a $\delta>0$ given any $\epsilon>0$, not for one $\epsilon>0$

Comment: 1. do you now a theorem which gives a connection between the limits of the function at the boundary of the interval and uniform continuity? 2. you shouldn't choose $\epsilon=8$. this should be arbitrary. 3. Do you know Heine's theorem?

Comment: 1. If $f$ is uniformly continuous on a set $A$ and $B\subseteq A$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $B$.

  2. If $f$ is continuous on a bounded close interval $A$ (e.g. $A=[0,2]$...) then it is uniformly continuous on $I$.

  3. Can you find a suitable $B\subseteq A$...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For given $\epsilon >0$, choose $\delta=\epsilon/12$, then for $x,y\in [0,2),$ such that

$|x-y|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|=|x^3-y^3|$

$=|x-y||x^2+xy+y^2|<|x-y|(|x|^2+|x||y|+|y|^2)<12|x-y|=12\delta=\epsilon$

Thus, for $\epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta >0$(independent of point where continuity is to be checked), such that $|x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Hence, Proved.

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking wrong ,but shouldn't it be $\delta=\epsilon/12$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I edited it.

Comment: Why epsilon/12 though?

Comment: Because $x,y<{2}$, so $|x^2+xy+y^2|<{4+4+4}=12$

Comment: because $(|x|^2+|x||y|+|y|^2)<12$ for $x,y<2$. so to make $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$, you need to have $|x-y|<\epsilon/12$

Answer (score 4):

For a quick way, recall that any continuous function is uniformly continuous on a closed interval $[a,b]$. If $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$ then it must be uniformly continuous on $[a,b)$ (with the same $\delta$ for every $\epsilon$).

Answer (score 1):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498542/how-do-i-show-the-uniform-continuity-of-tan-1-over-mathbbr/498560#498560).

**Hint:** Another approach is the mean value theorem. Here is a [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246249/showing-f0-0-and-fx-leq-m-implies-fx-leq-m-x).

**Added:**

> **Mean Value Theorem:** If a function $f$ is continuous on the closed interval [a, b], where a < b, and differentiable on the open interval (a, b), then there exists a point c in (a, b) such that
>   $$ f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}. $$

In your case, we start as

$$ \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=f'(\eta),\,\,\eta\in(x,y) \implies \frac{x^3-y^3}{x-y}=3\eta^2 $$

$$ \implies |{x^3-y^3}|=|3\eta^2||x-y|\leq 12|x-y| < \epsilon $$

$$\implies |x-y| < \frac{\epsilon}{12}=\delta. $$

Now, choosing $ \delta=\frac{\epsilon}{12} $, we have

> $$ |x-y|< \delta \implies |x^3-y^3|<\epsilon.  $$

Comment: would you care to elaborate some more?

Comment: @user1709828: See the added.

Comment: The implications at the end are a mishmash. To reach a valid proof, at least the last one should be reversed.

Comment: @Did: Thanks for the comment. It is corrected.

Comment: @Downvoter: There was a typo and it was corrected.

Comment: You are welcome. The implications at the end are still a mishmash.

Comment: For more detailes about $\delta-\epsilon$ approach see my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209440/how-to-show-that-fx-x2-is-continuous-at-x-1/209492#209492).

Comment: @Downvoter: There was no a real mistake. In fact it was left it to the OP to work things out.

Comment: The last part you just added is correct. The middle part is still wrong.

Comment: @Did: What middle part are you talking about?

Comment: Always the same for 3 comments now: the part which starts with "In your case" and ends just before "Now".

Comment: @Did: It is correct.

Comment: Mhenni, Mhenni, Mhenni... Not again?