# $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} 2\sin^4 t \cos^2 t dt$ is lipschitz continous right?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} 2\sin^4 t \cos^2 t dt$ is lipschitz continous right?

as $|f(x)-f(y)|\le2|x-y|$?

in general if $f$ is bounded then $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt$ is lipschitz continous, am I right?

Comment: Yes. You should add "... and integrable" to your condition for $f$.

Comment: :-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-ov:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o:-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just notice that

> $$ f'(x)=2\sin(x)^4 \cos(x)^2 \implies |f'(x)|\leq 2. $$

Now,  you can apply [mean value theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322890/uniform-continuity-of-fx-x3) to prove the assertion.